# How to move decimal point in bash

Tags: bash

I have a variable that is stored as "1.20E20". I would like for it to be changed to "0.0120E22". Is there a simple command to change this value? I tried

```
let nh=$nh/100
```

But that did not work; I assume it is because of the character value in the variable. I know there are various solutions; what is the best way to solve this?

Comment: do you need to change it to `0.120E21`? Do you want to divide it by ten, or just express the same value with a different form?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, I need it to change to 0.012E22 (I messed up slightly in the original question, but you were right in assuming).

Comment: Technically, a number in scientific notation is supposed to be `xEy` or `x • 10^y`, where `1 < x < 10` and `y` is the power of ten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a way to force `printf` to shift the exponent. Let's do it manually: multiply the coefficient by 10<sup>-2</sup>, and add 2 to the exponent.

```
n=1.20E20
m=2
IFS="E" read coeff exp <<<"$n"
new=$(printf "%.4fE%d\n" "$(echo "$coeff * 10^-($m)" | bc -l)" "$((exp+m))")
# => 0.0120E22
```

We can validate with:

```
$ printf "%e\n" "$new"
1.200000e+20
```

Answer (score 2):

I’d write a simple `bash` script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=${1%E*}
b=${1#*E}
echo 0$(<<<"scale=4;$a/10^$2" bc)E$((b+$2))
```

You just need to give it the values as arguments, first the number and then the shift:

```
$ bash /path/to/script 1.20E20 2
0.0120E22
  # or, as a oneliner:
$ bash -c 'echo 0$(<<<"scale=4;${1%E*}/10^$2" bc)E$((${1#*E}+$2))' _ 1.20E20 2
0.0120E22
```